# How to remove unconnected node properties in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and I've created some nodes and relationships to see how it works, 
but now when I want to clear everything and start from scratch I see that it is still saving the properties.

how can I remove those?

- I've attached an image showing the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of Neo4j ?

Have you called the following query to reinitialize your graph ?

```
MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n
```

Have of got some indexes ? List them by command:

```
:schema
```

Comment: yes, I have used the DETACH call, and still the properties remain. and when I use the :schema commend, it replies: No indexes; No constraints.